# CSS navigation horizontal submenu not directly below parent

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, submenu

I am a little stuck. I am trying to build a horizontal navigation bar, 1024px across, which will allow for a submenu to display below it. But i want the submenu to also be 1024px in width and to display directly below the navigation bar, vertically aligned.

At the moment the submenu appears but fixes its left side to the left side of the current `li` that you are hovering over. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

EDIT: So on mouse over it would look something like this: http://eventav.biz/site/example.jpg

Link to what I've done so far - 
http://www.eventav.biz/site/

```
ul.top_menu {
        position:               relative;
        margin:                 0;
        margin-bottom:          -1px;
        list-style:             none;
        display:                table;
        width:                  1024px;
        border:                 1px solid #111111;
        border-bottom:          1px solid #000000;
        border-radius:          10px 10px 0px 0px;
    }

    .top_menu li {
        display:                block;
        position:               relative;
        border-right:           1px solid #111111;
        float:                  left;
        margin:                 0px;
        display:                table-cell;
        vertical-align:         middle;
    }

    .top_menu li:first-child {
        border-left:            1px solid #111111;
    }

    .top_menu li a {
        display:                block;
        text-decoration:        none;
        color:                  #000000;
        text-shadow:            3px 3px 8px #3A3A3A;
        padding:                15px;
        height:                 30px;
        display:                table-cell;
        vertical-align:         middle;
        margin:                 0px;
    }

    #top_menu_item ul { 
        display:                none;
        margin:                 0px;
    }

    #top_menu_item:hover ul {
      display:                  block;
      position:                 fixed;
      margin:                   0;
    }

    #top_menu_item:hover li {
        width: 1024px;
        background-color: #666;
      text-align:               left;
      color:                    #FFF;
      font-size:                12px;
      margin:                   0px;
    }

<ul class="top_menu">
                        <li id="top_menu_item"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                        <li id="top_menu_item"><a href="#">OUR SERVICES</a>
                            <ul><li id="top_menu_item"><a href="#">test</a></li></ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="top_menu_item"><a href="#">EXAMPLES OF OUR WORK</a>
                            <ul><li id="top_menu_item"><a href="#">test</a></li></ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="top_menu_item"><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `position: relative;` from `#top_menu_item`
2. Set `#top_menu_item ul` to `position: absolute; left: 0;` instead
3. Remove left padding on `#top_menu` with `padding-left: 0;`
4. Add:

```css
#top_menu_item:first-child {
   margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Essentially, the problem was that you've been positioning your inner `ul` tag relative to it's parent `li`. Instead, the solution above positions the secondary navigation absolutely in relation to the primary navigation, and we use `left: 0;` to make sure it's completely left-aligned.

It's also against the standard to use an `id` multiple times on a page. Therefore I'd recommend changing `#top_menu_item` into `.top_menu_item` and changing the HTML accordingly.

Let me know if you have any problems!

Comment: Thank you very much. I fixed it using this information and the information from JoshC. I will change the id's to classes also. Thank you - EDIT: ive tried to thank you both but im not really sure how :-/

Comment: You don't quite have enough rep to upvote, no worries just 'pay it forward' :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the fixed positioning from the child `ul`, and replace it with `position:absolute`. Add in `left:0px`, and then remove `position:relative` from the parent `li`.

[**Working jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/XN24j/1/)

```css
#top_menu_item:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: fixed; /* Change this to position:absolute; */
  left: 0px; /* Add this */
}
    
.top_menu li {
  display: block;
  position: relative; /* Remove this */
}
```

Comment: Sorry i think i described it wrong. If you look at this link (http://www.eventav.biz/site/)

I would like the submenu thats dropped down to appear below the navigation. As if its just an extension of it, the same width and position but below it. If you hover over one of the links you can see its indented all the way to the position of the link.

edit: so on mouse over it would look something like this: http://eventav.biz/site/example.jpg

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much. CSS is confusing! Can you tell me why the navigation has a margin of 1px to the black line it is above? Also the submenu overlaps by 1px. I could fix this by using margin: -1px; but i just dont understand why it is like that anyway when I have set everything to margin & padding 0. 

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I used the margin-bottom: -1px to fix the gap. But the submenu isnt filling the full 1024px. I used the jFiddle script. Can you tell me why? And on chrome broswer the submenu is indented to th left 1px but not on internet explorer.

http://eventav.biz/site/

Comment: @ThomasHughes It's because of the 1px border.

Comment: Thank you i have fixed that. Just trying to sort the width now.

Comment: I figured the width problem is something causing the navigation bar to go beyond 1024px, according to measuring a screenshot. So ill look in to it.

thank you very much for your support!!